# FineUploader submitDelete Get FileName and Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I need to call a Web Service before the file is delete so I decided to use the "submitDelete" callback.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the Name of the File and its extension.

Does Fine Uploader have a method that I could call just get this information?

Below is my current code.

```
$('#uploader').fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: 'upload.asp'
    },
    deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        endpoint: 'Upload.asp'
    },
    multiple: false
}).on('submitDelete', function (id) {
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need this information?  What are you trying to do, specifically, in your `submitDelete` callback?

Comment: All of my image are being save under one directory. When I call the deleteFile is executes my backend process which deletes the file from the directory. This process works fine. However they client wants to save the history of the files that are being deleted. FineUploader DeleteFile method only pass the UUID. Or is it possible to pass the UUID, Filename and Extension as parameter when the DeleteFile is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass whatever parameters you want with the DELETE request.  In the `submitDelete` callback, for example, you can call the `setDeleteFileParams` API method, passing in the filename.  There is a `getName` API method that will return the name of a file, given the file's ID.

I just noticed that the `setDeleteFileParams` API method is not documented.  I'll open up a bug report and be sure to properly document that in 3.6.  This method works just like the `setParams` API method (same parameters).  Please note though, that parameters for DELETE requests will be part of the query string.

Inside your onSubmitDelete callback handler, the following code will retrieve the filename and add it as a parameter for the associated DELETE request:

```
.on('submitDelete', function(event, id) {
   var filename = $(this).fineUploader('getName', id);
   $(this).fineUploader('setDeleteFileParams', {filename: filename}, id);
});
```

Comment: Bug for lack of documentation opened up at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/820.

Comment: Do you have an example of the meothod setDeleteFileParams and how do I get the FileName? Thanks!!

Comment: To get the file name, use the `getName` API method.  Call `setDeleteFileParams` just as you would `setParams`.  Please see the [API documentation](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/api-fineuploaderbasic.md) for more details.

Comment: I'm confuse on how to use the API. Are these functions that could be call within the FineUploader? If so how do you call them? The documentation only show the method but not how to implements these methods.

Comment: Please don't post code in a comment.  It's very hard to read.  Since you are using the jQuery plug-in, please see [the relevant section](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/using-jquery-plugin.md#public-api--instance-functions) in the jQuery plug-in documentation that describes how to call API methods.  There are also several examples on the home page.  You can pass parameters along with the DELETE requests either via options or an API method.

Comment: So I tried using the example posted on the URL and I get an error "getName is undefined"

Comment: `getName` is an API method.  You must call it on the associated Fine Uploader instance, such as `$(this).fineUploader('getName', id);`

Comment: So I should place this inside the DeleteFile method and reference the setDeleteFileParams (setDeleteFileParams: Code to get Filename) Correct?

Comment: Ray, your example works great!! How you ever thought about adding the ability to get the file extension instead of the whole file name? It would be either to handle it on the server side if we know the extension without having to do a split.

Comment: Ray on the API documentation for the method 'setDeleteFileParams' its does indicated that if this method is used and the user  sets the setDeleteFileParams it will override any params previously set on the callback DeleteFile params:.

Comment: This discussion is getting a bit long and off-topic.  Please accept my answer if it solved your problem, which it seems like it did.  Also, it's quite simple to extract the extension from the filename client side.  Just use a regular expression.