# delete a file with fineuploader not clear

Tags: fine-uploader

I am trying to delete a file with fineuploader (pretty trivial right?). Here is the issue that i am having: the application generates some kind of v4 uuid (that is supposed to identify the file) and passes it the server script that is responsible to delete that file.

According to this issue tracker: 
**https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/733**, the author of the script stipulates:

> *you must parse this request, grab the UUID from the URI path, find the associated file, delete it, and then response with a 200*."

Now how do i get the "associated filename" from this UUID without going back to Javascript or how do i convert existing files to UUID so i can make the comparison? The v4 UUID is pretty random to me, so there might not be a way to get that value again...

I do know that i can pass other parameters to the delete request as explained here: [FineUploader submitDelete Get FileName and Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305517/fineuploader-submitdelete-get-filename-and-extension)
but why should I do that in Javascript? Why having the UUID in the request in the first place? Also i do not want to modify the application source code...

Could anyone shed some light on this issue for me?

Comment: How do you store your uploaded files? I think fineuploader supposes to use the UUID as filename. That way it sould be easy to delete it again.

Comment: I store the files keeping their original name, i do not store them by changing their name to this UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to be able to map the UUID to the assiciated file.  You probably should be doing this anyway since file names are never guaranteed to be unique.  If this map exists in some database or even temporary data structure, deleting the associated file is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Ray. 1. In The application that i am building overwriting the files is not a problem. 2. How would i have a map of UUID to files ahead of time since everything is happening in real time? I am assuming that upon saving the file to the server, i would have to also add an entry to some temporary database (or other data structure). Once i have that map, deleting will be a breeze of course. If that the case, i will be going that route and add the solution (PHP) here and Github so everybody can benefit from it.

Comment: As you mentioned, build that map as the upload (POST) requests for the files are handled server-side.  I planned on updating the PHP example  in the near future to include support for the delete file feature as well.  If your application supports iOS (iPhones, iPads, iPods) you will find that iOS names every uploaded file as image.jpeg.  So, this is one situation where you simply cannot rely on file names to identify a specific file.

Comment: ...rather iOS names every uploaded IMAGE as "image.jpeg".  For some odd reason, it appends an index to the end of a video only, such as "image_01.mov".

Comment: I managed to delete the file using my PHP "delete.php", but if delete fails i would like to let to inform my user.  What should the delete.php return? I have tried returning a json array with success== false but the javascript still return "success". Any idea?

Comment: @winteck Please read the documentation regarding the delete file feature.  http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/delete-uploaded-file-in-33.html

Comment: Got it! i just return "header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");" from my php file in case of a failure and that took care of it. I got to tell you that a little bit unorthodox, i expected to return a json object instead but it does work. Thanks for the blog post.

Comment: I'm not sure why this appears to be unorthodox.  If there is a problem deleting the file, then it seems natural to reflect that in the response status code.  By the way, a 500 code seems more appropriate in this situation.